# Kafka / why ssl key should be generated for each broker?

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I have two kafka brokers, and I want to use SSL encryption to kafka brokers. I read the [docs](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#security_ssl) and it says to generate ssl key for each broker.

I create ssl key and use the same key in two brokers. Why we cant create it once and use it in all brokers? Is it have any risk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The risk is that if one key is compromised now you have compromised all of the brokers instead of just one. Every organization has their own requirements for this kind of thing so I recommend checking with the security team that runs other distributed applications in your organization to see what they do and why.